# is there a way to know when a folder was deleted from windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I just wanted to know that is there a way to know when a folder was deleted from windows server 2003 or any windows OS?

Comment: programmatically? in which language?

Comment: not programmatically.Just by setting up something in windows

Answer (score 0):

There is a group policy you can enable in Windows Server that will record information like file/folder access and deletions. You would have to have had this audit logging enabled when the folder was deleted in order to tell *when* it was deleted.

Here is a blog post that explains how to set up this audit group policy. http://sogeeky.blogspot.com/2006/07/how-to-audit-and-track-file-deletions.html

You'll probably get a better answer to this question on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com).